# How to add jquery spellchecker plugin to WYGWAM

Tags: wygwam

How I would go about adding the [jquery spellcheck plugin](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/ckeditor.html) to WYGWAM?

Comment: Probably start by following the "Usage" instructions on the page you linked to. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I started following those instructions but got lost on step 4.  Don't wanna just hack WYGWAM. I'd rather do it properly (i.e. the way Pixel & Tonic intended, whatever that may be).

Comment: I doubt you will be able to do it without hacking Wygwam, at least to some extent. At the very least you would need to create a new ExpressionEngine add-on and write some code to integrate it with Wygwam. I don't know enough about it to point you in the right direction though, sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here’s an extension that should do the trick for you: [Wygwam jQuery Spellchecker](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/wygwam_jquery_spellchecker)

Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome - now I'm stoked. Thanks Brandon! I'll install this hopefully tonight and let you know if I run into anything.

Comment: Nice one Brandon!

Comment: Hey Brandon, so I've installed the extension and have encountered a bit of a snag.  In the WYGWAM editor configuration the new spell checker buttons appeared, and I added them to the editors I have setup.  However, on the publish/edit page the WYGWAM field now disappears. BTW, I followed all of the steps in the docs and double checked the folder path; I also tried with "defer CKEditor initialization" on and off to no avail.

Comment: Correction - I did not actually see the spell checker icons at all. I mistakenly thought the original spell check icons were the jquery ones. So backup a step - I'm not seeing the icons in the wygwam config editor.  Should they appear automatically in the icon bar?  (I am running WYGWAM 2.6.3 and EE 2.5.3)

Comment: page not found...

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your host has modsecurity enabled. Modsecurity might block the extension from loading giving you that 404.